# The operation < cannot accept the arguments: , [*empty-string*], [100]

Tags: app-inventor

I'm currently experimenting with App Inventor but am having trouble with my code. It the text box in my app, I want to have the ability to type a number and work out if its going to be more or less than 100 but I am getting the following message after entering any number in the text box while running the app:

"The operation < cannot accept the arguments: , [*empty-string*], [100]"

Any suggestions anyone? Thanks a heap in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is trying to tell you, that the textbox never should be empty.
To avoid that error, you might want to add another if statement like this as first statement:

```
if is empty Textbox1.Text
then set Textbox1.Text to 0
```

http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/text#isempty

Also it might make more sense to use the Textbox1.Text directly without using additionally a global variable, because you set that global variable only during the Screen Initialize event...